# Assumptions with conditions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How does one specify the assumption that a function is real for real arguments?

Compare

```
Simplify[Re[I f[x]], Assumptions -> f[x_] ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

with

```
Simplify[Re[I f[x]], Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals && f[x_/;x ∈ Reals] ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> -Im[f[x]]
> ```

How do I get zero in the second case?

Comment: Well, I know it does work in some cases, but pattern-matching-based assumption is never documented…

Comment: @xzczd How would you otherwise formulate the mathematical fact of this kind about the given function?

Comment: The first case will be `Simplify[Re[I f[x]], Assumptions -> f[x] ∈ Reals]`, but sadly I've no idea how to express 2nd case.

Comment: `Re[I f[x]] // ComplexExpand`

Comment: @BobHanlon No, `ComplexExpand` unconditionally assumes that all symbols are real. I need to impose a condition. For instance `ComplexExpand[Re[I (f[x] + f[I x])]]` gives me zero. But if `f[z]` is `Sin[z]`---it is a false statement.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[Re[I (f[x] + f[I x])] /. f -> Sin]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Exactly, that is because MA knows some properties of `Sin` function. But for more complicated functions like `MeijerG` MA does not have this knowledge. I want to impose this property.